# how to save form data of shopify php/reactjs app?

Tags: php, reactjs, ubuntu, shopify-app

I have created a custom PHP app, and for that app, I have created a simple form with textbox and button,
when I enter some text in the textbox then click on submit button then data should be saved.

but form data is not saved yet.

for data save what should I do ? in the file?

I don't know how to do with this.

developers, please help me with this.

how can I do this?

**App Development in PHP(Laravel/React JS).**

below is my code.

file name **WhatsappSharecart.jsx**

file path : **/var/www/html/shopifyapps/whatsapp_share_cart/resources/js/react/components/WhatsappSharecart.jsx**

```
import {gql, useQuery} from '@apollo/client';
import {Banner} from '@shopify/polaris';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Loading} from '@shopify/app-bridge-react';
import app from "/css/app.css";
import { useReducer, useState } from 'react';
import TableData from './table';

function WhatsappSharecart() {
    const [Yes, No] = useState("No");
    const handleChange = (event) => {
     No(event.target.value)
    }
    
    const [enable, setEnable] = useState("");
    const [buttonlabel, setButtonlabel] = useState("");
    const [cartmessage, setCartmessage] = useState("");
    const [buttonposition, setButtonposition] = useState("");

    const handleSubmit = event => {
       event.preventDefault();       
       alert(`Whatsapp Share Cart Enable: ${enable}`)
       alert(`Button Label Is: ${buttonlabel}`)
       alert(`Cart Message on Whatsapp Share Link Is: ${cartmessage}`)
       //console.log("Cart Message on Whatsapp Share Link Is :-",name);
     }

    const [Dafault, Left, Center, Right] = useState("No");

  return (
    <div className="wp_share_cart">
      <h1>Configuration</h1>

      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

      <fieldset>

        <label>
          <p>Whatsapp Share Cart Enable</p>
          <select value={enable} onChange={(e) => setEnable(e.target.value)}>
          <option value="">--Please choose an option--</option>
            <option value="yes">Yes</option>
            <option value="no">No</option>          
          </select>
        </label>

         <label>
            <p>Button Label Text</p>
           <input type="text" 
                  value={buttonlabel}
                  onChange={(e) => setButtonlabel(e.target.value)}
                  name="wp_share_cart_label"/>
         </label>

        <label>
        <p>Cart Message on Whatsapp Share Link</p>          
          <textarea value={cartmessage} onChange={(e) => setCartmessage(e.target.value)} />
        </label>

        <label>
          <p>Whatsapp Button Position on Cart Page</p>
          <select value={Dafault} onChange={handleChange}>
            <option value="default">  Dafault   </option>
            <option value="left">     Left      </option>
            <option value="center">   Center    </option>
            <option value="right">    Right     </option>                            
          </select>
        </label>
        
       </fieldset>
     
       <button type="submit">Save Configuration</button>

      </form>
    </div>

  )
}
export default WhatsappSharecart;
```

Comment: please someone help me on this.. i need help with this issue.